# How can I add an "IsDirty" property to a LINQ to SQL entity?

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, binding, dirty-data

I am binding my entities to an edit form in WPF. Within a DataTemplate, I want to be able to set the background color of the root container within a DataTemplate to show it has been changed and these changes have not yet been submitted to the database.

Here's a very simple sample that demonstrates what I'm talking about (forgive errors):

```
<Page ...>
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MyPageViewModel /> <!-- Holds reference to the DataContext -->
    </Page.DataContext>
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource = {Binding Items}>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate
                DataType="Lol.Models.Item"> <!-- Item is L2S entity -->
                <!-- In real life, I use styles to set the background color -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsDirty, StringFormat='Am I dirty? /{0/}'}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
</Page>
```

The example just prints out "Am I dirty? yes" or "Am I dirty? no", but you get the idea.

To do this, I'll need to add a public property to my **Item** (partial class, simple) *that can determine if the entity is dirty or not*. This is the tough bit.

```
public partial class Item
{
    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("hurf durf");
        }
    }
}
```

Outside of the entity, it's pretty simple (as long as you have the **DataContext** the entity is attached to). Inside, not so much.

What are my options here?

---

Edit: I don't think there's one good solution here, so suggestions for workarounds are welcome.

(Okay, similar questions exist, but they are all about how to determine this from **outside** of the entity itself and use the *DataContext* the entity is attached to.)

Comment: It won't do it for you but there isn't any reason you can't implement all the logic to track the original values and keep the entity in sync. With a large model it might be tedious but it should work.

Comment: Yeah, it would work, but it'd also be very tedious.  So is the other option, where you go through the pending changes in the DataContext.  But since a L2S doesn't reference its DataContext, you have to build that in (probably not a good idea) or you have to examine the entity externally...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the dbml generated classes, you should be able to implement a couple of partial methods like this:

```
public partial class SampleEntity
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        this.IsDirty = true;
    }

    partial void OnLoaded()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => this.IsDirty = true;
        this.IsDirty = false;
    }

    public bool IsDirty { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: The use of the lambda here is pure evil.  I like it.

Comment: I considered something like this, but it doesn't take into account the original state of the entity.  So false dirties are possible, I believe.  What's a good way to go about preventing that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you give me an example?

Comment: The false dirties could happen if the property is changed, then changed back to the original value. in the Property Changed event there is no way to tell if the sender's value is different than the original's value (I tried using reflection), and I didn't have luck with the PropertyChanging event (since linq2Sql doesn't send the property name)

Comment: @klogan - what you are looking for is more than the dbml code gen does for you. I ended up creating my own linq2sql code gen tool to add features I wanted, change the reference property naming and correct the on change events to let you know what property was changing. To track original values you would have to edit or subclass the dbml classes or do your own code gen. Have you looked into the entity framework instead?

Comment: Accepting as an answer; there is no good solution unless you do what @ongle did.